# How do I add custom XML tags to a NuGet .nuspec file?

Tags: nuget

How can I put my own tag in a NuGet .nuspec file? I'd like to add

```
<mycustomtag field="foo"/>
```

somewhere in the file.  If I add it under <metadata>, I'll get a schema validation error when I run *nuget pack* to build the package:

```
>nuget pack

The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'
has invalid child element 'mycustomtag' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'.
```

I'll get a similar error if I try to add the custom tag under <package>.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to put custom elements in NuGet's nuspec file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In certain cases, I need to (redundantly) publish the files within the NuGet package to a non-git source code control system.  In that publishing process, I already need to parse some of the XML in the .nuspec file, so it is convenient to have the .nuspec file contain all the information I need and to parse it all with an XML parser.  I can certainly just put a recognizable string in the <releaseNotes> text, or I can put the info in another file. Neither of those is as convenient as having the info in XML.